# Rails Dynamic Multi Model Form attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This problem has been killing me.  I played around with Ryan Bates complex forms, but I can't quite figure out my problem.
I have this schema:

```
Location has_many :targets
Target has_many :target_classifications
```

All locations are shown on the page.  A user may create a target for any location dynamically through jscript, which then adds a table row under the location 3 selects (that contain available classifications to the target) and a target value.  Any number of targets can be created for any location before clicking save.
I'm using rjs to render a target_partial, which has this code:
I'm using fields_for in this way:

for each select.  When sumbmitted, I get this hash:

```
"new_targets"=>
  {"7"=>[{"id"=>"13"}, {"id"=>"15"}, {"value"=>"67", "id"=>""}],
   "4"=>
    [{"id"=>"12"},
     {"id"=>"15"},
     {"value"=>"23", "id"=>""},
     {"id"=>"11"},
     {"id"=>"16"},
     {"value"=>"67", "id"=>""}]},
```

So, it separates each target by location ("7" and "4" in this case), but doesn't separate each target.  What I want is this:

```
"new_targets"=>
  {"7"=>[
          {"target"=>[{"id"=>"13"}, {"id"=>"15"}, {"tonnes"=>"67"}]}
        ],
   "4"=>[
          {"target"=>[{"id"=>"12"},{"id"=>"15"},{"tonnes"=>"23"]},
          {"target"=>[{"id"=>"11"},{"id"=>"16"},{"tonnes"=>"67"]}
        ]
  }
```

so I can iterate through each target for each location.  I can't seem to add in a new [target] brace in my field_for method (it blows up), but that's kind of what I want to do.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are doing this, but you need to specify a string instead of the object when using fields_for. I can't see the codes you have in your partial, so I may be way off. Anyway, the way I do it is in a helper:

```
def fields_for_target(target, &block)
  prefix = target.new_record? ? 'new' : 'existing'
  fields_for("location[#{prefix}_target_attributes][]", target, &block)
end
```

Comment: @brad: I'm not sure, but I think these "[]" in fields_for will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

This sort of issue is discussed here:

> http://wonderfullyflawed.com/2009/02/17/rails-forms-microformat/

But it seems to be a rails 2.3 solution (not an option for me).  Basically, I want a form like they've posted on the site:

```
<input name="creator[widget_attributes][0][id]" />
<input name="creator[widget_attributes][0][name]" />
<input name="creator[widget_attributes][0][price]" />

<input name="creator[widget_attributes][1][id]" />
<input name="creator[widget_attributes][1][name]" />
<input name="creator[widget_attributes][1][price]" />
```

Just some way to create a unique identifier for each target (or in this case, widget attribute) I want to add.  Kind of tough given that a new target is added with jscript.  I feel like there should be some way for rails to automatically do this for me

Answer (score -1):

Easy. Look up `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. :)

Comment: As I mentioned rails 2.3 is not an option for me at the moment.  So that doesn't work